# How to install a package from a local repository?

Tags: beamer, packages, miktex, repositories

I am unable to connect to the package repository server using MiKTeX due to a proxy error. How would I go about installing a package from a local repository? I am trying to install the package beamer. Where do I actually find the file to download?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get the packages from the miktex folder on ctan:

http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/

Put whatever you want to install e.g.

http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/beamer.tar.lzma

in some empty folder (outside miktex).

Beside this you need the three database files

http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma
http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma

Put them also in the folder. Then you can use the folder as local repository.

Comment: Tried that, I'm getting: ! LaTeX Error: File `etoolbox.sty' not found.

Comment: Well then you will have to install etoolbox in the same way.  http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/etoolbox.tar.lzma

Comment: I'm getting an unending number of missing dependencies. Is there any way to find all of them I need to use beamer?

Comment: Not really. You can search for some log and guess, but it would be easier to download the whole lot, e.g. with wget.

Comment: There are an enormous number of dependencies. I've manually download around 15 now. No end in sight,

Comment: Well I don't know what you are loading in your document, but for beamer itself it shouldn't be so much.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it working now. There were some other errors I fixed with a simple google search!

Answer (score 1):

From https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages, download to a directory on your h.d. `beamer.tar.lzma` and the 5 following files:

`pr.ini`, `files.csv.lzma`, `miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma`,  `miktex-zzdb2-2.9.tar.lzma` and  `miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma`.

You have to declare the local repository from MiKTeX console, Settings, like this:

[image]

Comment: This works for me for .tar.lzma packages.
How about .cab packages, for instance totpages.cab?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Well the obvious places to start are for downloading beamer are

1. https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=en
2. https://sourceforge.net/projects/latex-beamer/
3. might have to look at tex live for installing a local package repo ftp://tug.org/historic/systems/texlive/

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the following files and store them together in a folder named MiKTeX:

```
Requiredpackagenames.tar.lzma
miktex-zzdb1-2.9.tar.lzma
miktex-zzdb3-2.9.tar.lzma
```

After the basic Installation I opened the MiKTeX Console and selected under packages the local repository MiKTeX Folder with the files I downloaded before. Then start MiKTeX and you can install the packages from your own directory.