# Which one should I download and install for TeXstudio?

Tags: texstudio, miktex2.9, miktex-update

For my windows 8 (64-bit) system, I want to install updated TeXstudio.

[Here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/TeXstudio%202.12.6/) I found 2017 version 2.12.6. But there are several files in the folder, as follows:

[image]

Should I download all 7 files ? Or just the 3rd or 7th file would be sufficient?

I already downloaded and installed the third file, but some Tikz/PGF code is not running; otherwise, everything is ok.

For your information, I have MikTex 2.9. Do I need to update it as well?

If so, which version of MikTeX should I install?  [This version](https://miktex.org/download) is for windows 10/11. But I have Windows 8.

I need your guidance.

**Edit:** I tried to update MikTeX as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am selecting MikTeX folder, but still it says "local repository not found"

Comment: Why don't you use the official siite for 4.6.3? https://www.texstudio.org/#download It also links to older version on sourcceforge, which you have listed ... // MikTex has a console application, which allows you to check for updates and install them. Takes a while.

Comment: what is different in this question to your  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695186/which-latest-version-of-texstudio-to-install-in-windows-8-64-bit ? Why can't you update that question, but rather create a potential duplicate? It will probably removed soon ...

Comment: @MS-SPO, In the same official I found that [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/texstudio/files/texstudio/) of old version. When I installed the 2023 version of TeXstudio, the editor is not opening and giving error message says "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling it to fix the program".

Comment: @MS-SPO, this current question focuses on some selection of files for TeXstudio, very specific question while the previous question discuses a large concern. I didn't wanted to ask a big question, so splitted into two parts.

Comment: @MS-SPO, one important issue, I didn't find MikTex console in the windows search option. Thats why I am unable to update it. So I want install new version of MikTeX but then the problem is that lastest 2023 [version of MikTex](https://miktex.org/download) is for windows 10/11 while I have windows 8. I am bounded by several constraints.

Comment: in ...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2\miktex\bin\x64 you should find miktex-console.exe, which you can call there. If not, also this program seems to be installed improperly.

Comment: Please don't use random tags for your questions. What has your question to do with biblatex?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, because I am dealing with latex editor

Comment: Please read the tag description to learn what biblatex is.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, no that doesn't answer my question. Please read the two questions, they are different. Please do not dilute the question, because I am really at troubled situation with my latex editor

Comment: @learner The main problem is: You are riding a dead horse. Windows 8 (and also 8.1) is no longer supported by Microsoft. So it is vulnerable. You should not connect it to the internet, because this would endanger not only you, but also others. You should therefore not expect any serious developer to support this outdated Windows version. If you (instead of updating it) need to use such an old Windows **offline**, use it either with an old TeX + TeXStudio (e.g. from and old TeX Collection DVD) or try a virtual machine, e.g., with Linux + TeXLive.

Comment: @cabohah, yes I agree it might be the case.

Comment: The MiKTeX binary folder is not an was never a valid MiKTeX package repository. Installation from a local repository means, [you first have to create a local repository](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/482797/277964).

Comment: The outdated Windows thing is the elephant in the room, as @cabohah said. *Attention, personal opinion*: If you have an older notebook running some outdated Windows, this might be the chance to switch to an user-friendly GNU/Linux distro like Ubuntu. Works well with any up-to-date TL and even TexStudio.

Comment: @lukeflo, I understand. Is Ubuntu free for subscription ? or I have Windows 8, can I update it to Windows 10 ?

Comment: Most (but not all) Windows 8 computers can be updated to Windows 10. Try it (but as always make a backup!). But note, that Windows 10 support will end soon. Ubuntu is free of charge. But both are questions, that are not TeX related. Ask a Windows or Ubuntu forum for more information.

Comment: @learner, to be honest, I'm prejudiced. Switched from Windows to GNU/Linux 15 years ago an never regretted anything. Ubuntu is all free, as are.most of the programs. You can have a look without the need to install/use it. If you can update your Windows, might depend on the license you own. But Windows 10 is already dying too, since 11 is the newest version. This cycle never ends... (before someone complains, all this pro GNU/Linux, contra Windows stuff, is 100% my personal opinion ;) )

Comment: @lukeflo, Is [this](https://ubuntu.com/download) the official website of Ubuntu? Can you give idea how to install it ? Do I have to backup my documents?

Comment: → The last two sentenced in [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695195/which-one-should-i-download-and-install-for-texstudio#comment1725914_695195).

Comment: Seems to be a good site, but, as cabohah pointed out multiple times, for detailed informations ask the particular forum or at Ubuntu stack exchange