# Manually adding *one* package to MiKTeX

Tags: miktex, windows

I'm on Windows behind a firewall (you're offering your sympathies; I know; thanks). I need to add the package `xcolor` to MiKTeX.

I download `xcolor.zip` and unpack it in `c:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex` alongside the packages that came with MiKTeX.

Does there exist an "add to the index" MiKTeX command that does **not** need network access?

Does `miktexsetup` make it possible to set up a local repository [other](https://miktex.org/howto/local-repository) than through `--local-package-repository` and `--package-set=complete download`? Using this pair requires network access.

Comment: Yes.  First, use the MikTeX console to Settings->Direcdtories and add the directory containing your sty file.  Then use Tasks->Refresh file name database.

Comment: The word "manually" can take on different meanings.  The MikTeX console allows for a single package to be added or removed.  To update a package, I will go and uninstall it, then reinstall it, all from the console.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/482238/2388 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. I expanded on your comment. I'm unsure whether it's clean to install the dependency `mptopdf` also in `<dir>/tex/latex` or some other location is more appropriate, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is an expansion of a comment made by John Kormylo.

1. To avoid getting the message "this does not look like a [TDS](https://miktex.org/kb/tds); are you sure...", extract xcolor.zip into `<dir>/tex/latex` rather than just to `<dir>/`.
2. cd to `<dir>/tex/latex` and `pdflatex xcolor.ins` to generate `xcolor.sty`.
3. Using the MikTeX console to Settings->Directories, add the directory `<dir>` containing your sty file.
4. Use Tasks->Refresh file name database.

One problem with manual installation of packages (where "manual" is defined as downloading a `.zip` file from CTAN and inserting it by hand into a TeX installation) is that it's also necessary to handle recursive dependencies.

For example, `xcolor` depends on the package `mptopdf`.

To find out the dependencies, after the steps above, run `pdflatex usexcolor` on a `usexcolor.tex` file containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

which will give you:

```
The required file "tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii" is missing.
It is part of the following package: mptopdf.
```

and that will mean that you need to repeat the steps above for `mptopdf`.