# Problem installing colortbl

Tags: tables

I am having problem installing colortbl package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{delarray,colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\endarray{\crcr \egroup  \egroup\@arrayright  \gdef\@preamble{}\CT@end}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}({ll})
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there any other alternatives to \usepackage{colortab}?? I can not get it to work thanks

Comment: Show the log file.

Comment: 2019-11-10 19:49:51,415+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info: connect failed in tcp_connect()
2019-11-10 19:49:51,415+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
2019-11-10 19:49:51,415+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Line: 1612

Comment: Start the miktex console and try to install from there. If needed check the connection settings.

Comment: I have tried it but I got this error:connect failed in tcp_connect()

Comment: works okay for me, so it must be a local problem. If you are behind a proxy check the settings. Or use a local repository: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462203/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-local-repository/462216#462216

Comment: the file says tha the archive is either in unkown format or damaged

Comment: SOS I am sitll stuck with installing this package. Any other way to color my table please?

Comment: I got it at last! Thanks for the help.