# How to install packages manually in latest version of Miktex using Miktex console?

Tags: packages, miktex, texstudio

I am using the Texstudio environment for compiling my latex code. I need to import the mathtools package for my project. But it seems that I am getting this error"mathtolls.sty is not found". So, I thought that I need to manually install this package. When I search this on the web I found all the solutions for the older version of Miktex going to the maintainance folder, setting(admin) etc. But in the latex version, Miktex merges the maintainance to Miktex console. Can anyone suggest how to install this package manually using Miktex console?

Comment: if you really get the error "mathtolls.sty" not found you have typo in your code. Beside this you can find mathtools by searching for mathtools in the package tab and then select it and click on the + to install it.

Comment: when I try to install this way it gives me this error "Connection to mirror.hit.edu.cn could not be established".

Comment: well then try another mirror. Or check your proxy settings. or build a local repository and install from there: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388

Answer (score 1):

Launch the MiKTeX console, both as user and as administrator, select the `Packages` tab,  write `mathtools` in the form above the packages list window to filter, and  select `+` to add it:

[image]

Comment: when I try to install this way it gives me this error "Connection to mirror.hit.edu.cn could not be established".

Comment: In this case, try to change the repository (from the `Settings > General` tab).

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to change this repository?

Comment: Did you obtain this ‘General’ tab? You have a form to select where packages are installed from, and at the end of the line a `Change` button, from which you can select a repository from a list all over the world.