# How to solve "File 'currfile.sty' not found" problem

Tags: miktex, currfile

I use the same latex code, with the same versions of TexStudio and MikTex, on my two laptops. One runs the code smoothly; the other laptop gives the subject error, i.e., "**File 'currfile.sty' not found.**"
The first laptop is an 11th generation model, while the second is a 6th generation model. Both have Win 10 installed. I don't understand why the same code is run by the first laptop but not by the second one. I reinstalled Windows on my second system, but the problem persists.
I provided the MWC.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mwe}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{standalone}

\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\captionsetup[subfigure]{skip=-2pt}
\begin{document}
    \title{\huge Towards Spectrum Availability For Heterogeneous Users in Social Internet of Things}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `currfile.sty` is part of [package `currfile`](https://ctan.org/pkg/currfile). Because it is available as [MiKTeX package `currfile`](https://miktex.org/packages/currfile) you can install it, using the MiKTeX console.

Comment: BTW: The corresponding `\fi` to `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` is missing in your example. I think, the `\ifCLASSINFOpdf` should be removed. Note also, that class `IEEEtran` is not supported by package `caption`. You are getting a warning about this, shown in your screenshot.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/544595/277964

Comment: From the command line: ` miktex packages install currfile`