# Error: ".....mpm.ini:44993: the file has been tampered with."

Tags: captions, packages

I tried to compile my paper latex file after 5 years in TexStudio but it gave me an error indicating that the caption.sty file was not found. I checked the Package manager and understood that the caption package is not installed. so, I downloaded the latest available caption package from the web and change the repository direction to the caption package folder. then, I simply right-click on the caption in the package manager list and click on "+" to install the package but it keeps giving me the following error. Could anyone kindly help me to fix this issue? Thanks, Hamid

Error: ".....mpm.ini:44993: the file has been tampered with."

Comment: use the package manager to download and install packages, don't install them manually.

Comment: thanx, but in connection settings, it asks for a user proxy server, what should I do?

Comment: ask your IT, or setup a local repository: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388

Comment: I have already added those 3 database files to my local directory of the package, getting the same error. could you tell me how can I get the package from the web automatically?

Comment: No I can't, I don't know what your proxy is, that is something only your IT can tell you. Is your miktex up-to-date?