# Why does MikTeX say, the local folder is not a repository?

Tags: miktex2.9, miktex-update, repositories

I have an old local installation of MikTeX 2.9.6361 on a machine and want to update without access to the internet. Therefore I thought the easiest is to download a full repo with `miktexsetup_standalone --verbose --local-package-repository=C:\temp\miktex --package-set=complete download` and afterwards point either the GUI or the CLI package manager (yes this was still a MikTeX version without Console) to this folder and perform the update.

However after a successful download of more than 5000 files,  performing a `mpm --repository=C:\temp\miktex --find-updates` yields `Sorry, but "MiKTeX Package Manager" did not succeed.` and the log reads `2022-01-04 23:40:32,854+0100 FATAL mpmcli - Not a package repository.`

The same happens when using the GUI and pointing to the directory, thereafter I am told `Message: C:\temp\miktex does not seem to be a local package repository.`

With earlier versions of MikTeX I understood, that as long as the main version remains the same, one can update from the repo, only a change from 2.8 to 2.9 required a new installation. Why does my MikTeX 2.9.6361 not recognize the current repo as a correct one? Did I miss something during the download, or is there an issue with the big version gap?

Comment: This is clearly not an anwer, but in such case of a so outdated Miktex  I woukd make a fresh install in another diirectory. By the way, current Miktex default folder in now Miktex, without the annoying space and 2.9, which IMO is much more convenient.

Comment: Sure, this is exactly what I did. Nevertheless I thought that MikTeX usually was able to update even across major versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with MiKTeX 2.9.6637. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/462203/how-to-install-a-package-from-a-local-repository/462216#462216) answer specifies that you need the three database files to have a folder be recognized as a local repository. Apparently miktexsetup_standalone only downloads files 1 and 3 (which seems to be enough when working with newer MiKTeX versions). Downloading file 2 manually from [here](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/) and putting it in the local repository worked for me.

Comment: Sounds good, I have to try that!