# eqparbox.sty and biblatex.sty on MiKTeX 2.9 and TeXMaker

Tags: texmaker, miktex2.9

While trying to compile the following MWE (well, not actually working)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
sorting=ynt
]{biblatex}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

my MiKTeX distribution complains that it cannot download the files eqparbox.sty and biblatex.sty. I went into the MiKTeX options as an admin and refreshed FNDP, updated all formats and even tried to manually download the correct file. This is where it got interesting: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.

What am I doing wrong? What could be the problem MiKTeX has with installing those particular packages?

When trying to find the correct repository (in particular, trying to install from the internet), MiKTeX doesn't actually find a repository to install from, even though I am certainly connected to the internet (otherwise this post wouldn't be possible). Is this the actual problem? How can this be solved?

Comment: perhaps you have some proxy or something else blocking miktex. If everything fails you can always setup a local repository https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388