# Failed to update MiKTeX due to proxy authentication

Tags: miktex-update, software

I have tried to update MiKTeX 2.9, in the following way:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am unable to understand it. What is a proxy name and password ? Do I have to create it or is it already in my system (OS: Windows 8)?

I have followed the path: Control Panel-->User User Account and Family Safety-->Credential Manager, then I got the following page:

[image]

It is given in the image: user name and password. But the password is not viewable. I am not sure if I am in the right place or if we have to do something with the proxy setting in Chrome.

I appreciate your help.

**Edit:** According to the given comment of `Ulrike Fischer`, I have unchecked the boxes in the 3rd image from the top, and then proceeding, I got the following error message:

[image]

Comment: Try if it works if you uncheck the "use a proxy server"

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks.  The proxy message disappeared. Unfortunately, I got another error, cn not connect with the online update portal, as you can see the last image of my question (edited)

Comment: sorry but it looks as if something in your internet connection is blocking miktex. But I can't you why and how to repair that. Perhaps you really have a proxy and need its password. You could try to install from a local repository instead : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thanks. I have downloaded packages from [here](https://mirrors.cqu.edu.cn/CTAN/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/). However the files are in `Izma` formal. Do I have to unzip the Izma files before saving in a folder ?

Comment: No Miktex will handle that. Simply dump everything in a folder.