Failed opening of the MikTeX Setup Utility
I'm trying to use the MikTeX Setup Utility to change the package repository of my MikTeX Console, as explained here, so I've dowloaded it using the link provided here, but for some reason my computer is not able to open it. I don't receive any error message: simply, if I double-click on the MikTeX Setup Utility icon, nothing happens.
Any thoughts as to what might be going on?

well a command line tool should be used on the command line. But if you have already miktex installed why don't you simply open the console and change the package repository there?

I want to create a local package repository and it seems to me that using the MikTeX Setup Utility is the only way I can do it. Basically, my main problem is that when I try to install new packages on MikTeX so that I can then use them in LaTeX, I receive an error message saying "A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established", hence the need to change repository. These are the details of the code: code="7", url="https://api2.miktex.org/hello".

For a local repository you only need to copy files in a folder. You can do that with the utility (on the command line) but you can also download manually https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462216/2388

Oh. Thank you! Sorry, I'm very new to LaTeX: I've dowloaded my package of interest from CTAN and copied it into a new folder I've just created on my Desktop. Now do I need to select that folder as my local repository on the MikTeX console (in which case: I'm receiving an error message saying it's not a local repository), or can I directly use the package in LaTeX without passing through MikTeX?

Sorry, now it seems to work. I seem to have changed the repository on the console and to be able to use the package in my Overleaf file. Thank you for your help!
